# Is there another way to fix Yesod's nicHtmlField?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I've been rewriting my (fairly simple) website using Yesod as a way to get familiar with the framework. Part of that involves serving some simple static (but formatted) content. To do that I decided to use the nicHtml field that is described in the Yesod book:

http://www.yesodweb.com/book/forms

It allows simple formatting and, as the book says, "thanks to the xss-sanitize package, all user input is validated and ensured to not have XSS attacks."

However, all is not well. Some formatting seems to work when you enter it into the field, but gets wiped out somewhere between entry and submission. In particular, the form uses css embedded in 'style' attributes to do things like center text, and it is these css based formatting elements that seem to get wiped out.

I used print statements to check that it wasn't my code which was somehow messing it up. Since it doesn't seem to be, I assume that xss-sanitize doesn't like any embedded css and removes it. Modifying Yesod.Form.Nic to remove the call to sanitizeBalance appears to fix the problem, so that would seem to be the cause.

Now, I can just leave it like that, since editing these static pages requires being a trusted user anyway (i.e. me at the moment), so I don't care too much about validating out nastiness. But it feels like what it is, a hack, so my question is - is there any other way around this? Or is there another package I don't know about that provides a non-broken HTML editor field for Yesod?

Comment: Sounds to me like this should be fixed/worked around in Yesod. You might want to report it on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will you file a bug on the Yesod issue tracker for this? I think we are going to have to allow basic css through the editor no matter which editor we use. In your case of a trusted user, right now you could find the NicEdit field type and create a similar type that won't get filtered at all. Perhaps we should create such a field.

Comment: I'll file a bug report. I've already modified Yesod.Form.Nic in this way for my own project. It's a single line change to remove the call to sanitizeBalance.

Comment: Update: white-listed css styles are now allowed on github. A new package version will be released soon, and Yesod will at least use it in the upcoming 0.9 release.

Answer (score 1):

We're actually looking at other possible rich text editors right now for use in the Yesod website, so most likely whatever we use there will end up with a module in yesod-form. Most recently Greg pointed out [Aloha editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/) which on first glance looks pretty cool.

Comment: I guess the problems with the nicHTML field were known? If so, it might be a good idea not to use it as an example in the book, at least not without mentioning that some formatting doesn't work right with Yesod at the moment.

Comment: No, the issue you're raising wasn't known, we ran into a totally different bug on the Yesod site. This was all a relatively recent discovery, so we haven't updated things anywhere yet.